# How to get correct dependency injection path using wiredep?

Tags: javascript, wiredep

I am trying to use [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) to include the css and js files from bower in my app. I have the raw `index.html`(the html exculding bower css and js ) in `app/rawHtml/index.html` as shown in the folder tree below:

```
 app
   ├── bower_components
   │   ├── lib1
   │   │   ├── lib1.css
   │   │   ├── lib1.js
   │   │   ├── bower.json
   │   │   ├── package.json
   │   │   └── README.md
   │   ├── lib2
   │   │   ├── lib2.css
   │   │   ├── lib2.js
   │   │   ├── bower.json
   │   │   ├── package.json
   │   │   └── README.md
   │   │       ├── globals.js
   │   │       ├── locale-header.js
   │   │       └── test-header.js
   ├── index.html
   └── rawHtml
       └── index.html
```

I want to use the `app/rawHtml/index.html` to `app/index.html`. My gulpfile for `wiredep` is as follows:

```
gulpfile.js

gulp.task('bower:dev', function () {
   return gulp.src('app/rawHtml/index.html')
   .pipe(wiredep())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
});
```

Now the index.html file is created. But the dependencies are injected as follows, with respect to `app/rawHtml/index.html`:

```
 <!-- bower:css --> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/lib1/lib1.css" />                                                             
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/lib2/lib2.css" />

<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../bower_components/lib1/lib1.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/lib2/lib2.js"></script>
```

Instead of with respect to the destination file `app/index.html` as follows:

```
 <!-- bower:css --> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/lib1/lib1.css" />                                                             
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/lib2/lib2.css" />

<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/lib1/lib1.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lib2/lib2.js"></script>
```

I tried to do keep the source and destination `index.html` in the same directory, but I did not find the option to rename the destination file. How do I use wiredep so I can get correct injection path?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had the same problem. I guess you need to place your `index.html` in `app` dir before running `wiredep` command.

```
gulpfile.js

gulp.task('bower:dev', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/rawHtml/index.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'))
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
});
```